# HTML5 Controls Bar just on fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, fullscreen

Hi i have a video on my page (mobile view), by default its `controls` attr is turned off. I want to turn them on and show just on FULLSCREEN (I have a custom fullscreen button).

I was trying to add `$('#videoAbout').attr('controls', '');` and also `$('#videoAbout').attr('controls', 'true');` when Fullscreen is turned on, but it doesn't work on mobiles. On desktop resized to mobile resolution it works fine.

Can anybody help me out?

[Here is live example on my webpage.](http://dev.openform.pl/about)

Comment: Can you show example on playcode.io?

Comment: [link](http://dev.openform.pl/about) here is the live example